# Apache (WAMP) issue: “AH00404: Child: Unable to read socket data from parent”

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, wamp, wampserver

Frontend developer desperately trying to get a WAMP running on Windows 7 (Home Premium, 64 bit, SP1). I've tried WAMPSERVER and XAMPP. Starting the Apache service failed on both, returning the exact same critical error in their error.log-files:

> [Thu Dec 13 14:38:56.905257 2012] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 4868:tid 280]
>   (OS 109)The pipe has been ended. : AH00404: Child: Unable to read
>   socket data from parent
>
> [Thu Dec 13 14:38:57.028264 2012] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 5100:tid 408]
>   AH00427: Parent: child process exited with status 3 -- Aborting.

I've googled for over 2 hours for this problem and have tried several things. Checking/freeing up Port 80, using a different port, turning off MSSE's real-time protection, disabling LMHOSTS Lookup, dozens of reinstalls... All to no avail.

Please help :(

Answer (score 4):

Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services.  Find "Web Deployment Agent Service" right click and stop.  Start up Apache and see if it sticks.  If so, right click on Web Deployment Agent again and go to properties and set the startup type to Manual.

Comment: First of all, thank you, this helped me solve the issue on my laptop.  Secondly, I'll add a note here that in Windows 10 it is no longer "Web Deployment Agent Service", instead it is listed as "World Wide Web Publishing Service".  Stopped the service and set it to manual and xampp worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error log was this:

```
[crit] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : setup_inherited_listeners: Unable to read socket data from parent
```

The solution was that Apache was set to listen on IPv6 interface, but there was no IPv6 interface enabled.